# View Details on a "Failure" in Locust

Tags: php, python, slim, locust

I'm using a [locust](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) for the first time with a test suite written by other people.  I'm getting results that look like this

```
Name                                                          # reqs      # fails     Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GET /start-trip                                                  105 4928(97.91%)   11409    4214   15577  |   12000    1.60
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                            105 4928(4693.33%)
```

It's not 100% clear to me what a failure means.  i.e. does failure here mean 97.91% of the requests locust sent are returning some invalid HTTP status code?  Or is the service under test failing to live up to some performance criteria somewhere?  Or some third thing?

Is there a way I can view more information on what a failure means and what sort of responses the service I'm testing is returning?

(service under test is written in PHP using the slim framework, and running under PHP's built-in web service, if that matters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locust version 0.9.0

You can review details under the Failures tab if you're using the web interface, 
[image: failures]

they also (or if you're using --no-web) appear in the CLI  when you ctrl-c the process.

```
Error report
 # occurrences      Error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 75                 POST /api/users: 'ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host=\'localhost\', port=3000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/users (Caused by NewConnectionError(\'<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10cfc3588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused\'))"))'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: ha!  This probably seemed obvious to most folks, but these locust scripts were running in a docker container, and I never ctrl-c's to end them directly. Thank you for taking the time to answer.